# итерация элементов

Tags: javascript

Имеются наброски кода, который должен анализировать каждый элемент из списка элементов и всякий раз выбирать любой другой, но не тот, который уже был выбран (использован).

```
    function() {
    var items = ["John", "Mary", "Nick"];
    var uri = items[0]

    var itemslength = items.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < itemslength; i++) {

      if (uri = items[i]) {
        uri != items[i];
      }
    }.
```

Когда я прогоняю код, захватывается всегда только третий элемент (Nick). Когда же функция задействована снова, элемент должен сменится на первый (John) или второй (Mary), но не на третий (Nick), чего не происходит...подскажите, в чем может быть проблема? Как оптимизировать код?

Comment: Почитайте про синтаксис операций сравнения и присваивания, внутри цикла неадекватная конструкция

Comment: Потому что в условии `IF` происходит присваивание `=` а не сравнение `==`, `!=`

Answer (score 1):

`a = b;` это операция присваивания, в ссылку a кладётся b.

`a == b` это сравнение, результатом этого выражения является `true` или `false`.

В выражении `if` надо использовать сравнение а не присваивание.
`if (uri = items[i])` - неверно (хотя конечно в каких-то ситуациях и так можно написать, но так писать не надо).

`if (uri == items[i])` верно.

Кроме того что вы хотели получить в этом выражении, вообще не понятно

```
uri != items[i];
```

`!=` это тоже сравнение, в вашем случае оно ничего не делает.

Comment: `uri != items[I];`. 
Тут я бы хотел уточнить условие, что если на данный момент `uri` берет любой из элементов из списка `items`, то в следующей итерации (прогоне функции) `uri может быть любым из списка `items` кроме того, что уже был взят (items[i]), поэтому использован "не равно" (хотя, в джаваскрипте все по-другому, видимо)
Так как больше программирую на Питоне, интуитивно написал именно такой код...

Answer (score 0):

Вариант итерации без повтора прошлого выбора...

```js
var items = ["John", "Mary", "Nick"];

function fn(arr) {
  var temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  return function() {
    var out = arr.slice();
    out.splice(temp, 1);
    temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * out.length);
    out = out[temp];
    temp = arr.indexOf(out)
    return out
  }
}
var x = fn(items);
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  console.log(x())
}
```

Comment: если изменить `out.splice(temp, 1);` на `out.splice(temp, 20);`, то каждое следующее имя не будет повторяться среди предыдущих двадцати, так?  


                                   еще один вопрос: ваш output это список имен, а каким образом можно в качестве output иметь только одно имя? каждый раз получать только одно имя в качестве результата, чтобы эти результаты (имена) между собой не повторялись...

Comment: @Nikolai мне сложно ответить на ваши вопросы, они отражают полное непонимание предложенного кода, возможно вам проще будет просто перемешать массив ...